# How to create a admin user for a client in keycloak

Tags: linux, joomla, keycloak, saml

I have installed keycloak and integrated joomla with it by using saml protocol and now I need to create admin users in joomla by using keycloak console, I can create normal users in keycloak console but I need a user with joomla admin privilege. How do I do that please help me

Comment: Kind of sounds like something you might be better asking on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.